# Load an XML from Resources

Tags: c#, xml, resources

I have an embedded XML as Resource. When trying to load it like:

```
XDocument quoteDocument = XDocument.Load(Properties.Resources.Quotes);
```

I get an error:

> UriFormatException

How to properly load an XML from resources?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the following for XDocument

```
XDocument quoteDocument = XDocument.Parse(Properties.Resources.Quotes);
```

While this code works for XmlDocument

```
XmlDocument quoteDocument = new XmlDocument();
quoteDocument.LoadXml(Properties.Resources.Quotes);
```